# Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google maps distance matrix api in my project to get distance between 2 places. I have also enable this api in google developer console. But I am continuously getting error `ApiNotActivatedMapError`.

I am using sample code provided by google as [distance-matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) .

Answer (score 33):

When you use a library or service via the **Maps-Javascript-API**, and use a key, you only need to activate the **Google Maps JavaScript API** .

When you get the particular error with the linked example you obviously didn't activate the **Google Maps JavaScript API** for your project.

### Update:

since June 22, 2016 you need also to activate the related API(Webservice) for new applications when you want  to use the following features:

- geocoding service
- directions service
- distanceMatrix service
- elevation service
- places library

Comment: But HOW do you activate it?

Comment: @Konerak  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Yeah, that's how you get one. After you get one, you need to select it and walk through a maze of clicks and options to then find a page with all products. You click on the products one by one and activate each one on their seperate page. Was a bit of a search for me :)

Comment: Does it take a while to update? because im all activated, with a billing account. and i still get the error

Answer (score 9):

Old question.. But.. I had n similar issue recently with a ApiNotActivatedMapError using geocoding but Konerak's comment helped me get to [this](https://churchthemes.com/page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly/) really nice post.

Basically, you can activate your API's here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

Activating Google Maps JavaScript API along with the already activate Geocoding API solved my problem.

Hope it helps someone in a similar position :)

Answer (score 0):

This link is enabled API https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library. For default emulator and in iOS its disabled, but in this console you can active this API.