# API key doesnt work, still get error code same as if no API key

Tags: joomla3.0

Using SP Simple Maps module with Joomla 3.
Applied for API, got it, put it in place in module, no problem. But website still shows map as grayed out and error message same as before API:

> This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

[www.222project.com](http://www.222project.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is the error I am getting in console in your contact page 
Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error

You have to activate the API from console. Go to Dashboard and you can see the activate option.

There are some changes after June 22, 2016. there are some links that may help you

1. [Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124041/google-maps-api-error-google-maps-api-error-apinotactivatedmaperror)
2. https://superstorefinder.net/support/knowledgebase/google-maps-api-keys-usage-and-limits/
3. http://superstorefinder.net/support/knowledgebase/new-google-maps-after-22-june-2016-will-require-google-api-key/