# Google maps API not activated

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an API code and I want to use it to make a map on my localhost-page. The code for the map is:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

But when I open the page, it displays, there is an error, details in the Javascript Console. In there is following:

```
Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError
```

The API is activated, so what is the problem?

**Edit 1:**
As I just saw, I have just activated the wrong API.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700182/apinotactivatedmaperror-for-simple-html-page-using-google-places-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124041/google-maps-api-error-google-maps-api-error-apinotactivatedmaperror) helped me when I faced a similar problem. It could simply be that one or more of these services / API's haven't been activated:

- geocoding service
- directions service
- distanceMatrix service
- elevation    service
- places library

It is clear that your error refers to the fact that you haven't activated one or more of the above mentioned services (which are required after **June 2016**). So I suggest you have a look at their website:

**[developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-‌​key](http://%20developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bkey)**